# facebook login on ios

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a fully functional app, but I am getting this error when ever I click facebook login, however the login does work.

```
2016-03-31 10:57:42.433 Gibr[47848:1460979] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

Upon submitting to the ios app store I was rejected because they said that facebook login did not allow public profile creation. I do not understand what this means because It worked fine during ad hoc.

here is my info.plist:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the facebook developers site:

> This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your plist as described above, you can ignore this warning

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 , check at the bottom

So there should be some other issue related to the facebook profile creation , does it show any other error/warning ?

Are you doing something related to profile creation, If you can explain some more about your flow it will good?

Comment: Nope. No other errors or warnings. That is what I thought though as far as the first part was concerned